# How can I set a CSS name not to be a hash in a Webpack configuration file?

Tags: reactjs, hash, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I just wondering why my CSS name became **hash** after I build and run my React + [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) application. Is there advance configuration that I may have missed to set the CSS name as normal?

This is my Webpack configuration:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            applicationStyles: path.resolve(__dirname,'app/styles/app.css'),
            Clock: path.resolve(__dirname,'app/components/Clock.jsx'),
            Countdown: path.resolve(__dirname,'app/components/Countdown.jsx'),
            CountdownForm: path.resolve(__dirname,'app/components/CountdownForm.jsx')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};
```

This is the CSS name that becomes hash:

[image]

---

To be more clear, I add the source code of how I `import` and `use` the CSS on React:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Countdown from 'Countdown';
/* Import the CSS file */
import Styles from 'applicationStyles';

ReactDOM.render(
    /* Use CSS */
    <div className={Styles.box}>
        <Countdown/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 14):

This is what Webpack does by default to avoid identical CSS classes (from different CSS modules) to collide.

Here are three things you can do:

1: At the app level, you can add the following configuration to your Webpack to disable CSS modules. It is not recommended as it could lead to collisions and hard-to-find bugs.

```
options: {
    modules: false
}
```

2: At the file level, you can import it like this to prevent Webpack from obfuscating the class names. This is useful when importing third-party configuration libraries CSS files.

```
import '!style!css!golden-layout-css-base';
```

3: At the CSS class level, you can use `:global(.your-class-name)` to avoid obfuscating a specific class

```
:global(.container) {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: i got an ERROR when i tried number 2.  This is the message : `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: i tried number 1 and 3 as well. The css didn't work.

Comment: the third one is the best! thanks

Comment: Answer does not address the fact that OP most likely just wants to configure webpack to not obfuscate class names.

Answer (score 7):

In your Webpack configuration, the CSS loader needs a configuration for prefixed names. Basically `localIdentName:'[local]'` sets the pre-fixer as the local class name only.

For detailed info, you can look at [the documentation for CSS Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#localidentname)

```
 module: {
    rules: [

        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'style-loader' },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                        localIdentName:'[local]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The class name can be combined with an auto-generated hash using the `localIdentName` option of CSS Modules by setting it to `[local]_[hase:base64:5]`.

`[local]` here refers to the class name.

`[hash:base64:5]` means generate a Base64 hash string of length 5.

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
     'style-loader',
     {
       loader: 'css-loader',
       options: {
         modules: {
           localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

By setting the `css-loader` modules options to an object, you're essentially setting modules to `true`, but with specific options.

Setting the `localIdentName` to `[local]` completely defeats the purpose of using CSS Modules.

Comment: unless you're just maintaining references for 3rd party libraries